# Facebook pixel image in <head> results with HTML validation errors

Tags: html, facebook, pixel, facebook-pixel

After building a Wordpress site and setting the tracking list, the W3C validation fails. I examined the issues and found that Facebook's tracking code is causing the issue, particularly the following part being in the site's `<head>` part.

```
<noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
```

It's funny, because Facebook offically recommends inserting this code in the `<head>` part.

I solved it by separating the `<script>` part from the FB tracking code in the `<head>` element and the `<noscript>` part in the `<body>` element. The validation now passed just fine.

Wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this, especially for maintenance purposes? This way one can easily forget that the Facebook tracking is present in 2 places and forget to change either one when changing the pixel code.

Comment: _"It's funny, because Facebook offically recommends"_ - validity is probably not their main concern.

Comment: _"and forget to change either one when changing the pixel code."_ - if by "pixel code" you actually mean the pixel ID in this instance - well _separate_ that from the code then ...? Use a constant or a config setting to store the ID, and then insert the value of that dynamically in _both_ places ...